# Derivatives of two multivariable functions with respect to each other

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm working on a 3-D mechanics problem about how strains are related to each other. Its been a while since I've done any calculus and I haven't been able to find any examples similar to the problem I have right now.

Consider a set of strains in a particular coordinate system which are related by a linear transformation to a set of strains in x-y-z coordinates. For example, at a particular point:

$
\epsilon_1 = a_1\epsilon_x + a_2\epsilon_y + a_3\epsilon_z + a_4\gamma_{xy} + a_5\gamma_{yz} + a_6\gamma_{xz}
$

$
\epsilon_2 = b_1\epsilon_x + b_2\epsilon_y + b_3\epsilon_z + b_4\gamma_{xy} + b_5\gamma_{yz} + b_6\gamma_{xz}
$

And etc. for the remaining four strains. If I want to compute the derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\epsilon_2}
$$

How would I do it? My first shot was something like this:

$$
\frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\epsilon_2} = \frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\epsilon_x}\frac{\partial\epsilon_x}{\partial\epsilon_2} + \frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\epsilon_y}\frac{\partial\epsilon_y}{\partial\epsilon_2}+\frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\epsilon_z}\frac{\partial\epsilon_z}{\partial\epsilon_2}+\frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\gamma_{xy}}\frac{\partial\gamma_{xy}}{\partial\epsilon_2}+\frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\gamma_{yz}}\frac{\partial\gamma_{yz}}{\partial\epsilon_2}+\frac{\partial\epsilon_1}{\partial\gamma_{xz}}\frac{\partial\gamma_{xz}}{\partial\epsilon_2}
$$

And then using the coefficients to compute the derivatives. Is that correct?

Comment: Couldn't you just solve for $\epsilon_x$  in equation one, and the substitute into second?

Comment: Your notation is ambiguous? Since you have two equation first you need to fix two dependent variables, and consider other variables as independent variables, the using total derivative you can compute that